# Extracting match from text file if subsequent lines contain specific strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to pull certain lines of data from multiple text file using a certain match of data. I have that part working (it matches on the strings that I have and pulling back the entire line). That's what I want, but I also need a certain line of data that occurs before the match (only when it matches). I also have that working, but its not 100% right.

I have tried to accomplish pulling the line above my match by using the `-Context` parameter. It seems to work, but in some cases it is merging data together from multiple matches and not pulling the line above my matches. Below is a sample of one of the files that I'm searching in:

```
TRN*2*0000012016120500397~
STC*A3:0x9210019*20170103*U*18535********String of data here
STC*A3:0x810049*20170103*U*0********String of Data here
STC*A3:0x39393b5*20170103*U*0********String of data here
STC*A3:0x810048*20170103*U*0********String of data here
STC*A3:0x3938edc*20170103*U*0********String of data here
STC*A3:0x3938edd*20170103*U*0********String of data here
STC*A3:0x9210019*20170103*U*0********String of data here
TRN*2*0000012016120500874~
STC*A3:0x9210019*20170103*U*18535********String of data here
STC*A3:0x39393b5*20170103*U*0********String of data here
STC*A3:0x3938edc*20170103*U*0********String of data here
STC*A3:0x3938edd*20170103*U*0********String of data here
STC*A3:0x9210019*20170103*U*0********String of data here
TRN*2*0000012016120500128~
STC*A3:0x810049*20170103*U*0********String of Data here
STC*A3:0x39393b5*20170103*U*0********String of data here
STC*A3:0x810024*20170103*U*0********String of data here
STC*A3:0x9210019*20170103*U*0********String of data here
TRN*2*0000012016120500345~
STC*A3:0x9210019*20170103*U*18535********String of data here
STC*A3:0x810049*20170103*U*0********String of Data here
STC*A3:0x39393b5*20170103*U*0********String of data here
STC*A3:0x3938edc*20170103*U*0********String of data here
TRN*2*0000012016120500500~
STC*A3:0x810048*20170103*U*18535********String of data here
TRN*2*0000012016120500345~
STC*A3:0x810049*20170103*U*18535********String of data here
```

I'm trying to pull the `TRN*2` line only when the lines below each `TRN*2` have `STC*A3:0x810024` and `STC*A3:0x810048` in them, but again getting inconsistent results.

Is there a way that I could search for the `TRN*2` line and pull the `TRN*2` and the lines below it that contain `STC*A3:0x810024` and `STC*A3:0x810048`? If the lines below the `TRN*2` line do not contain `STC*A3:0x810024` and `STC*A3:0x810048`, then don't pull anything.

Here is my code so far:

```
$FilePath = "C:\Data\2017"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FilePath -Recurse -Include *.277CA_UNWRAPPED
foreach ($file in $files) {
  (Get-Content $file) | 
    Select-String -Pattern "STC*A3:0x810024","STC*A3:0x810048" -SimpleMatch -Context 1,0 |
    Out-File -Append -Width 512 $FilePath\Output\test_results.txt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work, because you're selecting lines that contain `STC*A3:0x810024` *or* `STC*A3:0x810048` and the line before them. However, the preceding lines don't necessarily start with `TRN`. Even if they did, the statement would still produce `TRN` lines that are followed by *any* of the `STC` strings, not just lines that are followed by *both* `STC` strings.

What you actually want is split the files before lines starting with `TRN`, and then check each fragment if it contains both `STC` strings.

```
(Get-Content $file | Out-String) -split '(?m)^(?=TRN\*2)' | Where-Object {
    $_.Contains('STC*A3:0x810024') -and
    $_.Contains('STC*A3:0x810048')
} | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ -split '\r?\n')[0]   # get just the 1st line from each fragment
} | Out-File -Append "$FilePath\Output\test_results.txt"
```

`(?m)^(?=TRN\*2)` is a regular expression matching the beginning of a line followed by the string "TRN*2". The `(?=...)` is a so-called positive lookahead assertion. It ensures that the "TRN*2" is not removed when splitting the string. `(?m)` is a modifier that makes `^` match the beginning of a line inside a multiline string rather than just the beginning of the string.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that worked perfect. I'm now being asked if there is a way to include the lines that contain the matches "STCA3:0x810024","STCA3:0x810048" for each "TRN*2".

Comment: Yes. Instead of selecting the first row from the split fragments add another filter to select the lines with the relevant strings.

Comment: Thank you very much